# FQL: Getting author_uid and tagged_uids for location_posts for a particular place

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, checkin

I'm trying to get a list of friends who have checked in / posted a status with place for a particular Facebook place. Also any of them who've been tagged in those posts.
With Facebook phasing out checkins, I'm using location_post table, which seems to contain the data I need anyway.

This is what I've tried:

`SELECT author_uid,tagged_uids FROM location_post WHERE page_id='116076945072769'`

I'm only getting results for the two posts that I made on that place, even though I've just made a post from another account (who I'm a friend with) with that particular place attached. Also, when I go to the FB page for that place, it lists this other user as 'Friends who've recently visited'.

Trying to get all location_post objects where the author is that user (let's call him Friend1), doesn't give me any results:

`SELECT author_uid,tagged_uids FROM location_post WHERE author_uid=<Friend1>`
(note, this user *is* my friend, I see it when I try to get a list of friends)

Trying to get a list of all friends who have authored or have been tagged in a location_post, I get a surprisingly small list:

`SELECT author_uid,tagged_uids,page_id FROM location_post WHERE (author_uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())) OR (author_uid = me())`

In particular, I see 10 entries for a particular user (Friend2). However, when I try this:

`SELECT author_uid,tagged_uids,page_id FROM location_post WHERE author_uid=<Friend2>`

I get 30 results. Too round numbers as well.

Any ideas on what could be causing the inconsistency? And why I wouldn't be seeing `location_post`s from one particular friend?

I tried getting all possible permissions, but it didn't help. This is all in FQL explorer.

Thanks!